# How to optimize these Django queries for faster execution?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have List of models named `campaign_list` as shown below, in every model there are some common fields **(like overall_score, audit_date, audit_id)**. I want to find the **average score** of for each month. I have written below code and it **works but the execution time is more**. I want to optimize the execution time. **Execution time increases as the number of records increases**(currently I have 200k+ records and adding).

```
# List of 40 Models 
campaign_list = [Model1, Model2, Model3, ....., ModelN]

# Method 1
campaign_score = sum([sum([j.overall_score for j in i.objects.filter(audit_date__range=[start_date, todays_date])]) for i in campaign_list])

# Method 2
campaign_score = 0
for i in campaign_list:
   score = sum([j.overall_score for j in i.objects.filter(audit_date__range=[start_date, todays_date])])
   campaign_score += score
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have a list of model classes, it's not trivial to do everything in a single query, but at least you can [use the `Sum` aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) to do the summing per model in the database.

```
# List of 40 Models
campaign_list = [Model1, Model2, Model3, ...]

campaign_score = 0
for campaign_model in campaign_list:
    res = campaign_model.objects.filter(
        audit_date__range=[start_date, todays_date]
    ).aggregate(score=Sum("overall_score"))
    if res.get("score"):
        campaign_score += res["score"]
```

Comment: Even this methods take much time to execute. for 60k records it took around 1.3sec. If I increase records to 200k+ then it'll be much slower

Comment: Well, do you have indexes on `audit_date`?

Comment: No. `audit_date` is a field in model so I don't have the Index of that

Comment: @IbrahimKhan I know it's a field in the model. I'm asking whether you've set `db_index=True` on it, so your RDBMS indexes it so you can make fast queries.

Comment: I am using sql lite 3 data base and i have not used index anywhere

Comment: @IbrahimKhan That explains why your query is slow. Please add `db_index=True` on these columns, create and run Django migrations that create the indexes, and try again.

Comment: So, @IbrahimKhan, any luck after adding indexes?

Comment: No. I had bunch of operations to be performed in series or at once and pass the data to front end. I ended up using Ajax. Now page will load fast and data will appear after some seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have different models with an **Audit** model foreign key and thus have the common field **audit_id**. So we can join the models using **select_related** ORM method. After joining the columns will be the different for each models as specially **overall_score**. We can aggregate the value using **F** of each column and will give you the total score.

```
Audit.objects.select_related('model2', 'model3', 'model4')
    .aggregate(
        score=F('overall_score') + F('model2__overall_score') + F('model3__overall_score') + F('model4__overall_score').get('score')
)
```

By using this query the only one query get execute. you can check by using

```
from django.db import connection, reset_queries
reset_queries()
Audit.objects.select_related('model2', 'model3', 'model4')
    .aggregate(
        score=F('overall_score') + F('model2__overall_score') + F('model3__overall_score') + F('model4__overall_score').get('score')
)
print(connection.queries)
reset_queries()
```

As @AKX told if you have huge data then you should go with index and save time.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't quite cut it with a dynamic list of 40+ models.

Comment: Also, this doesn't include the date filtering OP has...

Comment: Easy enough to expand this to a dynamic list?